# json_encode changes the display of emojis

Tags: php, json, laravel, emoji

Edit:
*Sorry I've edited the original post, it seems that when using json_encode is when the emoji style changes, is there anything that can be done to avoid this?*

Im using laravel 8.
I receive this data from a php query of a product page review, the string containing the message field includes a red heart emoji.

[image]

As I'm using Laravel Livewire, all variables are passed through a json_encode.

```
 $this->review = json_encode($this->review);
```

When doing json_encode, the emoji is shown with a small black character (an "ugly" version of the original emoji):

[image]

**How can I keep the original emoji style when doing json_encode?**

Comment: What do you mean by "How can I display emojis well". The emoji is displayed correctly.

Comment: @N69S In the string I receive, as you can see in the screenshot. The icon is a red heart while the html shows a black icon, not the "good" version of the emoji.

Comment: It's the font you are using that does that. change the font but keep in mind that colored font dont work on all browsers.

Comment: You try {!! $review->message !!}  ?

Comment: @proghasan yes, does not work

Comment: If you add your code in question section then i will try my pc.  i already try it's working my pc  $sticker = " Hello ";

Comment: Sorry I've edited the original post, it seems that when using json_encode is when the emoji style changes, is there anything that can be done to avoid this?

Comment: probably using JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE - or one of the [other flags](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) - it'd be helpful to put the text in the question, in addition to images of text.

Answer (score 1):

The displayed emoji depends on the font you are using and the operating system or platform on which it is displayed. You can see the browser console like interface where `dd()` dumps output is different from that of the browser html page. And even for the same font, different browsers will display the same emoji differently.

Added to these complications, there are intricate measures a browser takes to display fonts if you do not specify a font or you specify a generic one like "serif". Hence, you can enclose your data at source (where it is entered e.g., an editor) and at the destination (after using `json_encode()`) in tag and specify a specific css font-family to have some consistency and a level of control over what the user sees on the browser.

**Source**

```html
<span style="font-family: Helvetica">Me ha encantado ♥️</span>
```

**Destination**

```html
<span style="font-family: Helvetica">{{ json_encode($review) }}</span>
```

One other way to ensure consistency across platforms is to use an emoji font as described [here](https://css-tricks.com/it-all-started-with-emoji-color-typography-on-the-web/#aa-color-fonts-to-the-rescue) - you can get more from a Google search (e.g., [here](https://fsymbols.com)), though some platforms will still be incapable of displaying certain emojis the way you'd expect or displaying them at all.

Another option is to make your own emojis and include them as insert image option in your own custom editor. See some options [here](https://beebom.com/how-make-your-own-emoji/)

Comment: Sorry I've edited the original post, it seems that when using json_encode is when the emoji style changes, is there anything that can be done to avoid this?

Comment: @RichardMiracles, I will suggest you use some tag with a specific css font type in your output html to enclose the data.

Comment: @RichardMiracles see my update... I am guessing you want to display the output of `json_encode()` on the browser.

Comment: @RichardMiracles the way the emoji is shown internally (e.g., at the server) isn't as important as the way it is shown on the browser. Apart from beauty, you want some consistency on the client browser.

Answer (score 0):

In your blade, try the following code :

```
{!! html_entity_decode($this->review->message) !!}
```

or echo

```
 <?php echo $this->review->message; ?>
```

Comment: Does not work...

Comment: Sorry I've edited the original post, it seems that when using json_encode is when the emoji style changes, is there anything that can be done to avoid this?